# www.mydomainname.com/support - to - support.mydomainname.com

Tags: web, dns

I am just wondering how can I do this with my domain.

I have a support page on my website and access it like:

**www.mydomainname.com/support**

but I want to do it like

**support.mydomainname.com**

It might be a simple question with a very simple answer but I am having trouble and confusion regarding this.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a myriad of ways to do this, the simplest being a simple [302 redirect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302) on the page. Depending on your web server setup, you could also [setup a `.htaccess`](http://www.internetofficer.com/seo/302-redirect/) file to implement the redirect.